# Two particle Heisenberg model with field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, phase-transition

I'm having trouble solving a problem with a phase transition of this system. We are considering the following Hamiltonian:

$$H=-J \vec{S_1}\vec{S_2}-\mu b (S_{1z}+S_{2z})$$

And I've studied it in the common spin basis $\{|++>, |+->, |-+>, |-->\} $.

I've been asked to find a phase transition for the energy and I've found one from $|-->$ to $|+->-|-+>$ when $J<0$ and $b>0$. Then a problem occurs: I'm asked to suggest a term (called gap term) to add to the Hamiltonian to avoid this crossing of energy levels and after that to try and build one from the spin operators.

I've been thinking about the physical meaning of all this and I think I've got the gist of it. The system changes from an ordered system to a disordered one as we align the spin with an increase of $b$. So we should add a term that avoids this somehow.

But I really can't think what to add. I know I can add more magnetic field in other directions, but I don't think that's going to help.

I've been looking for information about the Heisenberg model with field but all the articles seem to look at it from a solid state physics perspective and also for many particles, not just 2.

Any guidance will be highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This isn't what people call the Ising model in a quantum mechanics context. The Ising model looks like $H=-J S_{1z}S_{2z}-\mu b (S_{1x}+S_{2x})$. Your ordering term is the one that couples the sites together, and your 'magnetic field' term points in a different direction and acts to disorder the system.

Comment: You wrote down what is called the Heisenberg model with an extra magnetic field term

Comment: Oops I'm really sorry, the question didn't mention the model so I thought it looked a lot like the Ising model, I'll try to fix that, but can you give any insight on the answer?

Comment: I would maybe try to solve it by addition of angular momentum, where you have the spin singlet state and spin triplet state, as both term of the Hamiltonian are diagonal in that basis.
In that basis, it is clear that for $J<0$, $b>0$ the first term will prefer both spins to be in opposite directions (the singlet) while the second term will prefer them pointing in the same direction.

Maybe this can direct you somehow to a solution

Comment: I didn't think about using angular momentum because our teacher suggested we tried to make one using onli spin operators. I'm pretty lost also because this is my fist time dealing with quantum mechanics

Comment: Spin operators are in a sense angular momentum, as they obey the same rules. Specifically, by adding two spins of distinct particles you get a representation of the total spin which has the same rules. Here, adding two spin-$1/2$ operators you will one state with spin 0, called the singlet, and three states with spin $1$, which are the triplet.

I am a bit baffled by the fact that this is a problem given to someone who has not dealt with quantum mechanics before. It requires some prior knowledge

Comment: Oh I know, my teacher definitely thinks we already know a lot about QM. If I don't make progress in a few hours I'll have to email him. I mean I feel like I've learned a lot in the month I've been studying this, but still some question just go flying over my head. Thanks for the help though